# Visual C++: Why class method from different compilation unit is called?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, c++17

I have two separate compilation units without any header files:

Unit a.cpp:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
class my_predicate
{
    const std::vector<int>& vec;
public:
    my_predicate(const std::vector<int>& container) : vec(container) { }

    bool operator() (size_t idx1, size_t idx2)
    {
        return vec[idx1] < vec[idx2];
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1,v2;
    v1.resize(10);
    v2.resize(10);

    std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end(), my_predicate(v2));
}
```

Unit b.cpp:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

class my_predicate
{
    const std::vector<char>& vec;
public:
    my_predicate(const std::vector<char>& container) : vec(container) { }

    bool operator() (size_t idx1, size_t idx2)
    {
        std::cout << "Why the operator from b.cpp is called?" << std::endl;
        return vec[idx1] < vec[idx2];
    }
};

void bar()
{
    std::vector<char> v1, v2;

    std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end(), my_predicate(v2));
}
```

The key difference in `my_predicate` implementation is the type of container used: `vector<int>` and `vector<char>`.

Formally unit a.cpp should know nothing about class `my_predicate` from unit b.cpp.

Weird things starts when `sort` in main from a.cpp is executed:

1. It calls the correct constructor from `my_predicate` in a.cpp
2. And then for sorting, suddenly starts to call `operator()` from `my_predicate` in **b.cpp** which it mustn’t know.

This is reproduced in Debug mode as well, so Whole Program Optimization is turned off here.

Am I missing something and now class definitions globally visible or this is a compiler bug?

Magic happens only if I have a dummy call to `my_predicate` in b.cpp (see dummy unused function bar in b.cpp).

As a bonus, if I try to rename `my_predicate` in a.cpp with VS Rename tool (Ctrl+R,Ctrl+R), it offers to rename it in both files.

Comment: Since neither of your predicates properly implements strict weak ordering you're not fulfilling the requirement for `std::sort`. You will usually get an assert from Visual Studio in debug builds for this.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, not only cleanup, I created minimal reproducible example from start.

Comment: Do both classes really have the same name?  Perhaps you should put them in (different) namespaces.

Comment: @RetiredNinja, you missed the point of the question. I am asking not why it doesn't sort, I am asking why operator() from unit b.cpp was called. This is before any strict weak ordering things. This is a question, how code in module a.cpp could know and see code in module b.cpp

Comment: Side note: Throw the build system a bone and help it out with [Anonymous namespaces](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Unnamed_namespaces)

Comment: @PaulSanders, yes, they do. If I rename one of the classes or put them in different name spaces, everything works fine. My question about exactly this behavior with the same names in different compilation units.

Comment: ODR violation: "There can be more than one definition in a program of each of the following: __class type__..." "as long as __all__ of the following is true:..."  "...each definition consists of the __same sequence of tokens__..."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition

Comment: @user4581301, works just fine with with anonymous namespaces, as well. My questions, what is wrong with my code with the same names of classes in different compilation units?

Comment: The code defines two different definitions of the class `my_predicate`. Don't do that: the behavior of the program is undefined.

Comment: @Damir Richard has it nailed. UB from ODR violation. You are at the whim of the gods which definition of `my_predicate` will be picked unless you lock the sucker into its compilation (translation) unit

Comment: @DamirTenishev What I'm saying is since the comparator is incorrect  any testing you do may be invalid. It turns out the always false case does not trigger the invalid comparator assert but always true will.

Comment: Recommendation: Don't leave extra bugs in the examples. You'll find someone (maybe many someones)  will zoom in on the wrong bug. And their answer might not even be wrong.

Comment: @RichardCritten, thank you so much. I have to read this again. I am confused, anyway. I understand the ODR, but is it really applied for class names which even not visible between modules? I was sure that since class name scope is from definition point to (in this case in absence of brackets) till the end of the file, but not in the other files. So, does it mean that I can't have the same names for classes through entire project (even internal for cpp unit) and compiler in not obliged to inform me about such issues?

Comment: @DamirTenishev The answer below already covers this.  Methods defined in a class are global names visible to the linker.

Comment: @user4581301, thank you for the pinpointing, you (and RetiredNinja) are right. Need to have only one failure point :)

Comment: @RetiredNinja, this is just abbreviated version of the real code to show the problem. Of course, my real code meets the strict weak ordering. I just don't want to put here tons of code. I am not asking what will happen when sorting starts its work, I am asking about this function call. Fixed the issue, anyway, to make the question more clear. Thank you for the catch.

Comment: Code with the same particular identifier was generated in two translation units, both with different implementations. Unless you take steps to lock them into a single translation unit, both will be visible. The compiler can't trap this for you and it looks like the linker doesn't care enough to inform you of the mistake. It found the name, it did the link, and its job is finished at that point. Wouldn't mind a warning, though.

Comment: @user4581301, this is really counter-intuitive. We have a class here, some lines above, we have the respective method to call and it takes (both in large project and minimal reproducible example) the wrong one from another module. If some developer would like to revenge company for something, he will introduce such classes across the project before leaving and people will struggle. Not all projects use anonymous namespaces, many of old C++ projects even don't have namespaces...

Comment: Funny thing with this question, it got -1 vote in a couple of seconds after publication. Seems somebody can read a question in a second :)

Comment: @DamirTenishev: "*is it really applied for class names which even not visible between modules*" C++ modules are not being used in your example.

Comment: @NicolBolas, thank you for catch, I meant compilation units, of course. So many terms, any step aside and I misuse another one, thinking about them as about synonyms (I know the difference). Anyway, the question about compilation units is on the table, still. See the comments below the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've defined `bool my_predicate::operator()` differently in two translation units and your linker therefore could pick any of them - or refuse the redefinition. The actual class definitions are different too, so that's another ODR violation.

In `g++`

```
g++ -o x a.o b.o
```

makes it use the definition in `a.o`, and

```cpp
g++ -o x b.o a.o
```

makes it use the definition in `b.o`.

See [Definitions and ODR (One Definition Rule)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition).

To not cause these types of ODR violations when you create classes (and functions etc) in your implementation (`.cpp`) files, put them in anonymous namespaces.

```cpp
// a.cpp
namespace { // anonymous namespace
class my_predicate {
    // a's definition
};
} // anonymous namespace
```

```cpp
// b.cpp
namespace { // anonymous namespace
class my_predicate {
    // b's definition
};
} // anonymous namespace
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255117/discussion-on-answer-by-ted-lyngmo-visual-c-why-class-method-from-different-c); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.